How can I fix the issue of StateFlow values not updating?
How can I fix the issue of StateFlow values not updating?

The value of StateFlow is not assigned to the BoardRequestDto object.
The latest value of StateFlow is not properly collected in the createPost function.

// PostBoardViewModel.kt
@HiltViewModel
class PostBoardViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val boardRepository: BoardRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<PostBoardUiState>(PostBoardUiState.Initial)
    val uiState: StateFlow<PostBoardUiState> = _uiState

    private val _title = MutableStateFlow("")
    val title: StateFlow<String> = _title
    
    private lateinit var boardRequestDto: BoardRequestDto

    private fun updateTitle(newTitle: String) {
        _title.value = newTitle
        Log.d("PostBoardViewModel", "Title updated: ${title.value}")
    }

    private fun createPost() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _uiState.value = PostBoardUiState.Loading

            boardRequestDto = BoardRequestDto(
                title = title.value,
                // ...
            )

            Log.d("PostBoardViewModel", "BoardRequestDto created: $boardRequestDto")

            try {
                Log.d("PostBoardViewModel", "Attempting to post board")

                val result = boardRepository.postBoard(boardRequestDto)
                Log.d("PostBoardViewModel", "API response: $result")

                when {
                    result.data != null -> {
                        val boardIdDto = result.data
                        _createdBoardIds.value += boardIdDto!!.boardId
                        _uiState.value = PostBoardUiState.Success(boardIdDto)
                        Log.d(
                            "PostBoardViewModel",
                            "Post created successfully with ID: ${boardIdDto.boardId}"
                        )
                    }

                    result.error != null -> {
                        val errorMessage = result.error!!.message
                        _uiState.value = PostBoardUiState.Error(errorMessage)
                        Log.e("PostBoardViewModel", "Error creating post: $errorMessage")
                    }

                    else -> {
                        _uiState.value = PostBoardUiState.Error("unknown error")
                        Log.e(
                            "PostBoardViewModel",
                            "Unknown error occurred while creating post"
                        )
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _uiState.value = PostBoardUiState.Error("netword error: ${e.message}")
                Log.e("PostBoardViewModel", "Exception while creating post", e)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Enum class: PreferredGender, PreferredAge, Region, Category, BoardStatus
enum class PreferredGender {
    SAME, ANY
}

// BoardRepository.kt
interface BoardRepository {
    suspend fun postBoard(board: BoardRequestDto): ResultResponse<BoardIdDto>
}

// ResultResponse
data class ResultResponse<T>(
    var data: T? = null,
    var error: ResponseError? = null
)

@Serializable
data class ResponseError(
    val status: Int,
    val code: String,
    val message: String
)

// BoardRequestDto.kt
@Serializable
data class BoardRequestDto(
    val title: String,
    // ...
)

// BoardIdDto.kt
@Serializable
data class BoardIdDto(
    val boardId: Int
)

// PostBoardIntent.kt
sealed class PostBoardIntent {
    data object CreatePost : PostBoardIntent()
}

// PostBoardScreen.kt
@Composable
fun PostBoardScreen(
    viewModel: PostBoardViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    val title by viewModel.title.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    when(uiState) {
        is PostBoardUiState.Initial ->
            Column {
                AccompanyTitleInput(
                    title = title,
                    onTitleChange = {
                        viewModel.handleIntent(PostBoardIntent.UpdateTitle(it))
                    }
                )
                // ...
            }
        is PostBoardUiState.Loading -> CircularProgressIndicator()
        is PostBoardUiState.Success ->
            Column {
                AccompanyTitleInput(
                    title = title,
                    onTitleChange = {
                        viewModel.handleIntent(PostBoardIntent.UpdateTitle(it))
                    }
                )
                // ...
            }
    }
    // Receives a value for each item from the user
    // When you click the post button on the top bar, a post is created.
}

// GetTopBar Function in MainActivity.kt (app module)
@Composable
fun GetTopBar(
    currentRoute: String?,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val viewModel: PostBoardViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    
    // TopAppBar of PostBoardScreen
    Screen.Post.route -> {
            BackButtonWithTitleTopAppBar(
                screenTitle = "동행 모집하기",
                onNavigateUp = { navController.navigateUp() },
                onPostClick = {
                    viewModel.handleIntent(PostBoardIntent.CreatePost)
                    navController.navigate(Screen.Home.route)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

How I Tried

Values ​​are not collected even when combine and collectLatest are used.
Check whether the value is set properly before calling createPost -> It is set properly
Until the createPost function is called, the StateFlow value is checked to see if it is the latest value, but it is set to the initial value within the function.
Copilot and GPT do not solve the problem


Please reduce your code to a self-contained [mre]. Remove everything that is not necessary to reproduce the problem, but make sure everything that is needed to run the code is there (import statements are not needed). Links to code on external sites are not sufficient. That said, why do you collect the flow in your view model? Make sure you only collect in your composables by using collectAsStateWithLifecycle.

@Leviathan First of all, thanks for pointing out how to post the question. I modified the code to collect the Flow values from the viewModel and use collectAsStateWithLifecycle on the Screen instead. But still, if I take a log, I can see that each value changes based on the user's input (for example, the title field). Assigning the changed values directly to a new BoardRequestDto object did not solve the problem. And thanks for your answer :)

Is boardIdDto a data class?

@Bumblebee, when you have created a [mre], can you please [edit] your question and replace the code there with it?

@KenWolf Yes it is a data class. The code is in the text.

@Leviathan I just updated the code. I'm not sure I did it right...

Are you sure every single view model function is really needed to reproduce the issue? Can't you remove one, without the problem disappearing? I guess you can probably remove most of them. Please make sure your [mre] is actually minmal, meaning "as short as possible".

Also, make sure the [mre] is actually reproducible. That means that all code that is needed is there. But your code is missing a lot of classes, at least these: PostBoardUiStateinterface, PreferredGender, PreferredAge, Category, BoardStatus, ResultResponse -- But before you add them, please verify first if they are actually needed, otherwise don't add the declaration, just remove their usage.

If you have difficulties creating a [mre] then create a new project in Android Studio and copy the code from your question there. Then edit it until it compiles, while keeping in mind to make it as short as possible. Then it is reproducible, and it is minimal. Your current code is more than 250 lines. I bet you can reduce it to 100 at most.

You do not call your PostBoardViewModel.createPost() function anywhere.
Perhaps, that is the reason?

I had declared the onPostClick in the GetTopBar function! Since I wasn't very familiar with StateFlow, I thought the issue might be there. However, I discovered that the real cause was that the module (app) calling the createPost function is different from the module (home) where PostBoardViewModel and PostBoardScreen are declared, causing the ViewModel instance to behave separately when created. Since I was using hiltViewModel, I assumed it would be the same ViewModel instance, but it wasn't.

Anyway, there is no invocation of PostBoardViewModel.createPost() inside the PostBoardViewModel, and since this method is declared private, you can't invoke it from another place.
So even if handleIntent() is declared in the superclass of PostBoardViewModel, how can it invoke createPost() function?

fun handleIntent(intent: PostBoardIntent) {
    when (intent) {
        // ...
        is PostBoardIntent.CreatePost -> createPost()
        // ...
    }
}

In the handleIntent() method of PostBoardViewModel, the createPost() function is called when processing the PostBoardIntent.CreatePost intent through a when statement. This allows the private createPost() function to be indirectly called from outside the class via handleIntent().
